# Отключить ряд скриптов, если не авторизирован

Tags: php, javascript

На станицу всегда подгружается ряд скриптов js(файлов), которые при условии, что пользователь не авторизирован на сайте, попросту не нужны.
Как их подключать, отключать?

Есть лишь одна идея:

```
<? if($auth):?>
<scrpt></script>
<? endif;?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, только лучше создать массив с именами скриптов и условиями их отображения, а потом в одном цикле их выводить или не выводить. Так вы сможете модифицировать список, не добавляя дополнительных

```
<? if($auth):?><? endif;?>
```

это усложняет поиск и восприятие.